# SendGrid API error codes and messages?

Tags: api, error-code, sendgrid

I have looked all over in their site and forums and wiki, but so far I have not been able to find an answer to this question.

Where can I find a list of SendGrid API error codes and messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Web API reference](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/index.html)

[Web API v3 reference](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html)

Comment: I know the wiki link, I've been there, I still have not found a list of the error codes and messages.

Comment: SMTP service returns standard SMTP error [status codes](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt). What kind of API do you use? I see all needed information in wiki. For example description for [REST API](http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=web_api:bounces) to manage your bounces lists. At the end of list there is single available error message: "Email does not exist".

Comment: I guess I needed to be more specific. I'm using the WEB API, mainly to send mail, not really using other calls. If you look at their page http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=web_api:mail there isn't a list of error messages; the response just has generic "errors" field that doesn't contain a code, just a message. This makes it really hard to know if one of the user/sub-users sending mail through theAPI and entered an incorrect user/key, or something wrong happened in our end trying to construct the message.I guess for bounces there is only one possible error message, but not for sending

Comment: @Onema. SendGrid doesn't recommend to use WEB API. Instead of it, proposes to use SMTP service. If you enter invalid username or key you will get HTTP 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Yep, thanks. They reorganized site structure. I have corrected link.

Answer (score 0):

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html

This explains each of the errors or status codes raised.

if you get a 4xx, try with a different key with different permissions.
if you get 2xx, you are done.if it's a 5xx, then there is problem/error on the server side.

Happy Hacking